# Livewire 3 - Modal keeps on adding backdrop on page render creating black screen

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am using Livewire 3 and the new Navigation features.

I have a modal in a component, included on a page - however each time I nagivate from then to the page with the modal, each time I open it it gets a darker background till it turns black (basically keeps rendering it each time I leave the page)

How can I prevent this from happening?

```
<livewire:admin.pet-codes.generate-pet-codes />


<button type="button" class="btn btn-alt-primary push" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#generate-pet-codes">Generate Pet Codes</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="generate-pet-codes" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="generate-pet-codes" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="block block-rounded block-transparent mb-0">
                <div class="block-header block-header-default">
                    <h3 class="block-title">Modal Title</h3>
                    <div class="block-options">
                        <button type="button" class="btn-block-option" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="block-content fs-sm">
                    <x-forms.text-input type="number" placeholder="Amount" name="amount" />
                    <form wire:submit="generate">
                        <div class="mt-3">
                            <x-forms.button title="Generate" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="block-content block-content-full text-end bg-body">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-alt-secondary me-1" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure modal id (generate-pet-codes) is unique on the page. If you are including this component multiple times on the same page, the modal IDs should be unique for each instance of the component.
You can use the `key` attribute in the Livewire component tag to make sure Livewire treats different copies of the same component as separate entities:

```
<livewire:admin.pet-codes.generate-pet-codes :key="'generate-pet-codes-' . $uniqueIdentifier" />
```

#### Keys aren't optional

If you have used frontend frameworks like Vue or Alpine, you are familiar with adding a key to a nested element in a loop. However, in those frameworks, a key isn't mandatory, meaning the items will render, but a re-order might not be tracked properly. However, Livewire relies more heavily on keys and will behave incorrectly without them.

Also see: [Nesting](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/nesting#rendering-children-in-a-loop)

Comment: Thanks - but it's like it renders the backdrop of the modal every time I use Livewires new navigate feature - so when I leave the page and come back each time and I open the modal the background is darker till it blacks out the page or I refresh the tab - currently it's only the one modal on each page it's not going through a foreach or anything.

Comment: @EthanPatchell ok well, whenever you navigate away from the page, ensure that you close the modal as well. You can do this by adding a method that closes the modal when the component is dehydrated (meaning it's no longer on the page). You can use the `dehydrate` method in Livewire.